# content with absolute position not showing in all browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, absolute

i'm building one site with wordpress+gantry framework, with responsive layout selected, and i have in the left side of the screen one picture above background. this left picture ( some kind of vertical sidebar withouth other content) is positioned absolutely with next code:

```
div.imgleft{
content: url('http://coszminart.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/laterala.png');  
position: absolute;
margin-left: 0px; 
margin-top: -1px; 
max-height: 1020px;
height: 100%;
max-width: 570px; 
background-size: cover;
z-index: 1000  !important;
}
```

the div.imgleft i inserted above header, in the template index.php
THE PROBLEM: the left image is not showing in iexplore 10, 11, latest mozilla, just in chrome and android phone. If i verify with chrome/firefox inspect tools, the css code is loaded ok. I've read that absolute positioning is cross browsers compatible, why is not working, is something wrong with my code? 
![enter image description here][1]

Thanks for any help, sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.**

So use

```
 background-image : url('http://coszminart.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/laterala.png');
```

instead of content

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/Az5GG/1/

Comment: hello. if i use background-image, the image is not showing in any browser. it's working just with content. i've discovered the need of :before, :after, but after introducing them, the left image does not reacting to Window size, it's just at maximum height. please enter on http://www.coszminart.ro to understand. thank you.

Comment: thank you, the fiddle was loading too slow and i was thinking it's not working. problem solved :)

Comment: AlwayZ Welcome Dude :)